# Extracting data from HTML Tags using Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

This is my code, in the last four lines I am trying to get the name of player from the h3 tag.

When I use `player_name = player1.h3` it gives the right h3 tag which is `<h3>Marc-André ter Stegen</h3>`
but I am not able to get the inner text  `Marc-André ter Stegen` using  `.txt` or `get_text` instead I am getting an empty string.

The same methods are working just fine in another program.

```
from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup



header = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36',
}

url = 'https://www.ea.com/games/fifa/fifa-20/ratings/fifa-20-player-ratings-top-100'

response = get(url, headers=header)
html_soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

player_container = html_soup.find_all('ea-container', attrs={'slot': 'container'})
player1 = player_container[0]
player_name = player1.h3.get_text()  # or player1.h3.text 
print((player_name))

#reslut: Empty String
```

Comment: Your output is not reproducible here. I am getting an output from h3 tag as `Marc-André ter Stegen` from <h3>Marc-André ter Stegen</h3> in `player_container[0]` content

Comment: Yes that is right, I used the wrong name , but are you getting the text only without h3 tag?

Comment: Yes I am getting exact text without tag. What is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add `for a in player1.h3:`
Code:

```
from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup



header = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36',
}

url = 'https://www.ea.com/games/fifa/fifa-20/ratings/fifa-20-player-ratings-top-100'

response = get(url, headers=header)
html_soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

player_container = html_soup.find_all('ea-container', attrs={'slot': 'container'})
player1 = player_container[0]
for a in player1.h3:
    print(a)
```

Output:

```
Marc-André ter Stegen
```